# oozie over hive to fetch the data from table

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, oozie-coordinator, bigdata

I am trying to do automation through oozie over hive.I wrote simple hive query for  creation of table and select queries on that table.When I submitted the same script.Script goes to running mode and doesn't execute.I checked the yarn application -list ,job was hanged on 95%.Hive table had been created successfully but not able to fetch data from table.Please let me know how to resolve this problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Workflow.xml

> 

```
<action name="hive2-node">
    <hive2 xmlns="uri:oozie:hive2-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <prepare>
            <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/hive2"/>
            <mkdir path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data"/>
        </prepare>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <jdbc-url>${jdbcURL}</jdbc-url>
        <script>script.q</script>
        <param>INPUT=/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/input-data/table</param>
        <param>OUTPUT=/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/hive2</param>
    </hive2>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>

<kill name="fail">
    <message>Hive2 (Beeline) action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

[script.q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02zH3.png)

**job.properties**

> nameNode=hdfs://***.***.***.***:8020
>       jobTracker=**.**.**.**:8050
>       queueName=default
>       jdbcURL=jdbc:hive2://***.***.***.**:10000/default
>       examplesRoot=examples
>
> ```
> oozie.use.system.libpath=true
> ```
>
> oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/hive2

Comment: Always look on the bright side of things: the job should die eventually, when the delegation token expires (after 7 days?) and then you will be able to inspect the logs... unless, of course, if your JobHistory is set to purge the logs after 7 days -- in which case you will have nothing at all.

Comment: Any chance the job might be stalled because of a table lock held by another session? Did you try a `SHOW LOCKS` command in Hive?

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by _"select queries on that table"_ in the context of a background batch job -- do you expect Oozie to dump the results somewhere in the YARN logs??

Comment: i want to do queries on that table.In this case i have used 
Insert overwrite directory '${Output}' select * from test;